# Joining tables on columns with comma separated values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table1: mas_book_author

```
author_id   |    author_name     
------------+----------------
 1          | jhon
 2          | roobini
 3          | virat
 4          | sachin
 5          | siva
 6          | priya
```

Table4: mas_bk_accession_entry

```
id(int)(pk)  | author_ids(varchar)
-------------+-------------------
1            | 1,5
2            | 5,1
3            | 2,5
4            | 3,5
5            | 4,5
```

my result should be like this:

```
author_name |count
------------+------
 jhon,siva  | 2
```

This is my SQL Query

```
select b.author_name,COUNT(*) as totbook 
from mas_bk_accession_entry a
   join mas_book_author as b 
     on b.author_id in (select cast((unnest(string_to_array(f.author_ids,',')) ) as int) as author_ids 
                        from mas_bk_accession_entry f)
where a.author_ids = '1,5'
group by b.author_name
```

Comment: Don't store comma separated values. The problems you have with your queries are a direct result of the bad database design

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok, is there any solution ??

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization - make your database 3NF and your life will be easier

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simplify your join condition and you need a string_agg() to get the comma separated list of author names:

```
select string_agg(author_name,','), count(*)
from mas_book_author b
  join mas_bk_accession_entry e on b.author_id = any(string_to_array(author_ids,',')::int[])
where e.author_ids = '1,5';
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/NVNBH72654

But you should really fix your data model. Storing comma separated values like the `author_ids` column is a really, really bad choice.

Comment: Thanks for ur time,

Comment: finally i got answer

select b.book_name,c.publisher_name,(select string_agg(author_name, ',') as  
     author_names from mas_book_author where author_id in ('1','4') ), COUNT(*) from mas_bk_accession_entry a
join mas_book_title as b on b.id=a.title_id
join mas_book_publisher as c on c.id=a.publisher_id
where a.publisher_id = 1 and author_ids = '1,5' and a.title_id = 3
group by b.book_name,b.id,c.publisher_name

book_name |publisher_name |author_names |count
----------+---------------+-------------+------
 jhon,siva  | jhon,siva  | jhon,siva   | 2